# launching an app within a vb.net project

Tags: vb.net, process, system.diagnostics

I try to lunch an executable file within my windows form vb.net application, but the first screen lunched were **maximized**..i want to be as it is, in minimized state..

my code is:

```
    Dim oProcess As System.Diagnostics.Process 

    Dim oPSI As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

    oPSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized

    oPSI.FileName = "path\application.exe"

    oPSI.Arguments = ""

    oProcess = Process.Start(oPSI)
```

Comment: i get the solution
the fault is hereoPSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized

Comment: `oProcess.oPSI.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;`

Comment: are you it is c#? :)

Comment: it should be normal not hidden

Answer (score 1):

```
oPSI.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
```

Remove this line

Answer (score -1):

I you launch you application from a terminal does i work?
if yes you can use

```
 System.Console.Write()
```

to do it like in the terminal but from your programm.
I think you can tell the terminal to open it in minimize like so:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("start /min apli.exe")
```

Good luck!